# What’s the difference between 円 and 月 as character components?

Tags: character-components

What’s the difference between 円 and 月 as character components?

If we look at 青 and 靑.

The bottom of 青 is:

> 月

and if we look at 靑, it's bottom is:

> 円

靑 is said to be an 异体字 of 青 and [zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=9751) says that

> 拼音qing1【青】的旧字型

just old form.

What’s the difference between 円 and 月 as character components?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**円** and **月** are both graphical corruptions. The original form of the character did not have those components.

**靑**/**青** was originally comprised of **屮** (*sprouting plant*) and **井**, which gave the sound. The bronze script form looked like

[image]

In ancient scripts, 井 as a component was frequently interchanged with **丹**. The graphical form of 丹 originated as 井 plus a small horizontal stroke in the middle. See, for example, the oracle bone forms

井:

[image]

丹:

[image]

In 靑/青, this happened as well:

[image]

On the bottom part, the form which came from 井 morphed to 月, while the form which came from 丹 morphed to 円.

Note that the top has actually been written with several similar components; you may find 青 variously written with 屮/生/木 on the top in ancient times. For clarification, the bronze script forms shown here actually contains **生**, but 生 ultimately comes from 屮 with the addition of two horizontal strokes.