# What does this seal stamp on Chinese painting mean?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, character-identification, poetry, seal

Is this seal the name of an artist or poet? How can I find him?

[image]

Is this translation okay?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Thank you for every answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

all some seal and looks like ,,Shi Qing´´?

Comment: Prior research effort **is** clearly indicated, no need to close this question.

Comment: I don't understand the actual question here, the questioner seems to have already answered it (`poet signature`). The seal stamp **is** the poet signature, and are the same two characters as the calligraphic ones given just above the seal stamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S = Simplified Chinese version
T = Traditional Chinese version
F = The final version in calligraphy

- S: 故园春意浓，花开鸟声碎
  T: 故園春意濃，花開鳥聲碎
  F: 故園春意濃，花開鳥聲碎
  Time: 壬戌春月

  **Remark**:
  開: The character 開 writes to the simplified Chinese character 门, which comes from cursive version of traditional Chinese character 門, and a 开 inside.

  **Translation**:
  The spring of hometown is evident everywhere, the flower opens and the bird chirp liquidly.
  The last 壬戌 year is 1982, 春月 (spring-months) may include Jan, Feb and Mar. It should mean the season of spring here, not a certain month.
- Time: 庚申冬月

  **Translation**:
  November, 1980.
- S: 梅竹相间寒意去，翠鸟枝头独春鸣
  T: 梅竹相間寒意去，翠鳥枝頭獨春鳴
  F: 梅竹相间寒意去，翠鳥枝头独春鳴
  Time: 戊辰春月
  Author: 石青

  **Remark**:
  头: The cursive character 头 is very sloppy, writes to two linked dots. It is difficult to determine which character it is, if you are not a calligrapher, or whithout the context.

  **Translation**:
  The chill is gone with mume flowers, while the spring bamboo is coming, the kingfisher tweets alone on the tree branch.
  The last 戊辰 year is 1988, see above for 春月.
- Title: 居庸之春
  S: 游此关，见桃花盛开，又时值九九建国五十年大庆，故写之
  T: 遊此關，見桃花盛開，又時值九九建國五十年大慶，故寫之
  F: 逰此関，见花盛開，又時值九九建国五十年大庆，故写之
  Time: 己戊夏
  Author: 石青

  **Remark**:
  [逰](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/js/9030.htm): A variant version of [遊](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/js/904A.htm).
  関: The character 関 or 關 like 開 above, the simplified Chinese character 门 with a 关 inside.
  : The above 木 and bottom 兆, same as 桃.
  開: The same as the above 開.
  九九: It may refer to the ninth day of the ninth month in Chinese lunar calendar here.
  青: The cursive version, the bottom 月 in 青 likes a マ.

  **Translation**:
  Spring of the Juyong Pass
  Touring this Pass, seeing the peach blossoms fully, meantime it is September 9th of the 50th anniversary of the State founding, so write it.
  There isn't a 己戊 year, it may be 1999, a 己卯 year, according to the context 建国五十年. 夏 means the season of summer.

See also:
[天干地支对照表](http://xh.5156edu.com/page/z8170m8067j19742.html)
[Sexagenary cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle)
[Juyong Pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juyong_Pass)

Comment: It's 时值九九, not 九月。The sign after 九 means "this character the same as previous one".

Comment: @thinwa 感谢指正这就改过来

Comment: “九九” here means the year 1999 obviously.

Comment: @thinwa 你也可以帮忙修改一下

Answer (score 2):

The signature is 石青, 
After googled the name, I found at least 3 painters named 石青 on the web, both mainly draw birds and flowers.

But compare the calligraphy, it does not look like same person.

[image]

All the 壬戌 year:

2年、62年、122年、182年、242年、302年、362年、422年、482年、542年、602年、662年、722年、782年、842年、902年、962年, 1022年、1082年、1142年、1202年、1262年、1322年、1382年、1442年、1502年、1562年、1622年、1682年、1742年、1802年、1862年、1922年、1982年。

Based on the style of the calligraphy and the poem, I think it is painted in 1982.

Answer (score 2):

The characters to identify are **石青**.「石」is easy enough to identify in seal script.

---

「青」is written in the variant form「」. Note that neither「青」nor「」resemble the original form at all, being originally comprised of「屮」(*sprouting plant*) and「井」(phonetic component) (see [another answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28196/what-s-the-difference-between-%E5%86%86-and-%E6%9C%88-as-character-components/28198#28198) I wrote on the glyph origin of「青」). Taking the original form

[image]

we morph「井」a little bit then add「口」to get

[image]

and

[image]

and finally the monstrosities of variants

[image]

These are mostly variants from the latter half of the [Zhou Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty) (Spring and Autumn, Warring States) that have been made redundant after [Qin Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin%27s_wars_of_unification). This directly leads on to the Seal Script form

[image]

---

Note, the addition of「口」mentioned earlier was a Warring States practice, and was actually pretty standard in the [State of Chu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)),

[image]

while not at all in the [State of Qin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state)).

[image]

Our current way of writing「青」is descended directly from the Qin variants.

Answer (score 1):

故园春意浓 花开鸟声碎

故园 means 故乡: native place or hometown.

Source: https://www.jayxun.com/what/%E6%95%85%E5%9B%AD/spec/7wIm

The poem means:

hometown in very spring time, 
flower blooming with clear and melodious bird song.

---

士戎春月 says the poet wrote it in the spring month of some year.

The artist is not famous, so I can't find this poet. I can't find him even in Chinese web sites.

Comment: very interesting,...... he was a poet and painter together?
or the painter has transcribed the poems.
painting is hand painted ....................the search would be reduced if it were found out how old it is.

Comment: I think it's not a poetry, just an inscription(题跋) which describe what he was painting.

Comment: and it should be 壬戌, not 士戌. possible year of 壬戌 : https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A3%AC%E6%88%8C